# Append not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have this HTML

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Phone</dt>
    <dd id="pmbb_phone"></dd>
</dl>
```

Now I want to append on success of ajax request into `id="pmbb_phone"`

I am using this code

```
$('#pmbb_phone').text=response.data['phone'];
```

But My code cant work

I am also using below way but not work

```
 $('#pmbb_phone').html=response.data['phone'];
```

Comment: Confusing jQuery with JS syntax. Use `$('#pmbb_phone').text(response.data['phone']);` or `$('#pmbb_phone').html(response.data['phone']);`

Comment: So, this should be closed as typographycal error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix Javascript with jQuery

**Syntax for Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("pmbb_phone").text = response.data['phone']; 
document.getElementById("pmbb_phone").innerHTML = response.data['phone'];
```

**Syntax for Jquery**

```
$('#pmbb_phone').text(response.data['phone']);
$('#pmbb_phone').html(response.data['phone']);
```

Comment: There's no `text` property in JS, it's `textContent`.

Comment: That's only for options, not for other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as mentioned in comments by Tushar, you are mixing up the usage of JS and jQuery.

i.e. you need to update from

```
$('#pmbb_phone').text=response.data['phone'];
$('#pmbb_phone').html=response.data['phone'];
```

to

```
$('#pmbb_phone').text(response.data['phone']);
$('#pmbb_phone').html(response.data['phone']);
```

Secondly, in subject you are looking for `append`. However, the above functions will not append but replace the html.

To append, you need to use `append` function.

```
$('#pmbb_phone').append(response.data['phone']);
```

For reference, [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)